# Spring JDBC Framework Conditional Prepared Statement

Tags: spring, jdbc, conditional-statements

```
public ResultSet getAdCampaignDetailsbyName(ADCampaignDetails Obj,
            Connection conn, ResultSet rs, PreparedStatement pstmt) throws SQLException {

        String query = "select adCampaignName,adCampaignId from AdCampaignDetails";
        query += " where 1=1 ";

        if (Obj.getAdCamapignName() != null)
            query += " and adCampaignName = ?";
        if (Obj.userId != "")
            query += " and userId = ?";

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        int i = 0;

        if (Obj.getAdCamapignName() != null)
            pstmt.setString(++i, Obj.getAdCamapignName());
        if (Obj.userId != "")
            pstmt.setString(++i, Obj.userId);

        System.out.println(" Q : " + query);

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();


        return rs;
    }
```

I am new to Spring , in this above query,  i have used two conditions , How to execute query with condition in Spring JDBC Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SimpleJDBCTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html).

```
    // SQL query
    String query = "select adCampaignName,adCampaignId from AdCampaignDetails where 1=1";

    // Map with parameter value
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (adCampaignName!=null){
        parameters.put("adCampaignName ", adCampaignName );
        query += " AND adCampaignName = :adCampaignName"; 
    }
    if (userId!=null){
        parameters.put("userId", 1);
        query += " AND userId= :userId"; 
    }

    // Execute query using simpleJDBC Template
    List<AdCampaignDetails> resultList = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(query, new customRowMapper(), parameters);
```

You can build the query string accordingly, just add coresponding entries in map.
Check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-simplejdbctemplate-querying-examples/) for details.

Comment: After write code as above i got exception as "Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select adCampaignName,adCampaignId from AdCampaignDetails where 1=1  AND userId= :userId]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.HashMap. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use."

Comment: the above exception came when  i have passed adcampaignname = null

Comment: SimpleJdbcTemplate is depreciated since Spring 3.1.. NamedParameterJDBCTemplate is added for serving this purpose.